# how to make textbox content always uppercase

Tags: php, html

i want to make the value of a textbox in a form always in uppercase and i use this code

```
<tr>
            <td width=70>No. Polisi</td>
            <td width=10>:</td>
            <td width=30>
            <input type="text" id="nopol" type="text" name="nopol" maxlength="10" size="26" style="text-transform:uppercase" /> </td>
            <td width=1></td>
        </tr>
```

but when i click the submit button, the textbox that i give that code for the uppercase text. the data that i get from that textbox is change into lowercase (inside of my database)

Comment: You would need to use your server side code to do that - what server side language are you using to put the data into the database?

Comment: i use php and ajax for the on click function

Comment: You can use [`strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) on the php variable before you send it to the db and to make it uppercase in the front end you can use `text-transform:uppercase` in your css

Comment: where i must place code {strtoupper} ? in the $_post variable?

Comment: thx Pete.. i got that fix now ehehhehe..
i place that code for convert format in $_post variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the front-end you use css to target the input type text and use text-transform to uppercase : below is a working fiddle.

```css
input[type="text"]{
text-transform : uppercase

}
```

```html
<form action="">
 <input type="text" id="nopol" type="text" name="nopol" maxlength="10" size="26">

 <input type="submit" name="submit" formmethod="POST">
</form>
```

Then in your server side use php's `strtoupper()` function to convert the text to uppercase

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $nopol = strtoupper($_POST['nopol']);


        echo $nopol;

     }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

text-transform: uppercase is css property. It only affects the user display. To convert it into uppercase use javascript or jquery

```
<table>
  <tr>
            <td width=70>No. Polisi</td>
            <td width=10>:</td>
            <td width=30>
            <input type="text" id="nopol" type="text" name="nopol" maxlength="10" size="26" style="text-transform:uppercase" /> </td>
            <td width=1></td>
        </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/ onclick="getValue()">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Write the javascript function

```
function getValue() {
alert(document.getElementById('nopol').value.toUpperCase());   
}
```

https://codepen.io/SESN/pen/zZQKxW?editors=1111

Comment: i've try almost same with your code but the text will be changing into lowercase when i submit the data into my database

Comment: Print the post data in php to see whether r u getting the uppercase letters or not. Before sending data in ajax, make sure that did u converted the val to uppercase.

Comment: it will change the data into uppercase when i input it into database?

Comment: i will try it 1st

Comment: u can also use strtoupper() in php before saving it into database.

Comment: use of js or jquery is not the best option at all

Answer (score 0):

**add your html**

```
<input id="nopol" type="text" name="nopol" maxlength="10" size="26" style="text-transform:uppercase" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)"/>
```

**add your javascript**

```
function upperCaseF(a){
    setTimeout(function(){
        a.value = a.value.toUpperCase();
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: what if the user's browser have js disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
style="text-transform:uppercase"
```

does a visual transformation only. Your actual input will retain the format you entered. You have to convert to UPPER after you post the data to your server in order to save it in Uppercase.